# Solving first order initial value problem numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I want to find the solution $y_0(t)$ of the linear first-order ordinary differential equation

$$y'-(1/t)y= t \text{sin}(t)$$

satisfying the initial condition $y(\pi /2)=0$. I know how to do this analytically using the integrating factor and such, but how do I solve for this numerically (and what exactly does that mean anyway)?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: numerically means picking a scheme i.e. shooting method to solve the ode by numerically stepping through time to get a solution that matches the conditions? does any of what I just said make sense?

Comment: See here: http://faculty.olin.edu/bstorey/Notes/DiffEq.pdf

Comment: so I am basically guessing the solution, what you said makes sense, but I still don't understand where to start.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$y'-(1/t)y= t \text{sin}(t)$$

Let $y(t)=tz(t),y'(t)=z(t)+tz'(t)$, So:
$$z+tz'-z=t\sin t\implies z'=\sin t\implies z=-\cos t+\color{grey}{\rm C}$$
So:
$$y=\color{grey}{\rm C}t-t\cos t$$
Now:
$$y(\pi/2)=\color{grey}{\rm C}\pi/2-(\pi/2)(0)=0\implies \color{grey}{\rm C}=0$$
So:
$$y(t)=-t\cos t$$

Comment: I think @Akaichan is asking for a numerical solution.

Comment: @KittyL he says "I want to find the solution y0(t) of the linear first-order ordinary differential equation" and if he knows the function he can get all values of y for any t!

Comment: He also says "I know how to do this analytically using the integrating factor and such, but how do I solve for this numerically (and what exactly does that mean anyway)". So he knows the function and he can get all values of y. However he just wanted to know what it means by "solving it numerically".

Comment: Oh @KittyL you were right.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand  your question. Is it like:

" I know the analytical solution and how to put in required boundary condition. How do I impose boundary conditions into a numerical solution, because I have nowhere to plug them in and myself verify / check up answer like in the analytical situation? "

If that is your question, the answer is:

You *don't* need to do all that. You choose RK4 or whatever method, simply plug in $ y(\pi/2) = 0 $ and press the RUN button.

Else I cannot say.